Get LocalDate from the @RequestBody, convert it to dd/mm/yyyy format, convert it back to LocalDate and store it in the database
I am creating a Rest API applicaton which tracks users` expenses. I have date variable of type LocalDate and the default format is yyyy-mm-dd but I want to store dd/mm/yyyy in the database
what I tried was get the localDate from RequestBody, format it to dd/mm/yyyy (which returns string) and convert it back to LocalDate. However, date is still being stored default format, yyyy-mm-dd. I think the problem is in LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter); because it converts back to the default format or ignores the new format. Not sure but this my assumption
Here is my code:
@PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Expense> addExpense(@RequestBody @Valid Expense expense) {
        
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.UK);

        LocalDate date = expense.getDate();

        String dateString = date.format(formatter);

        LocalDate formattedDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
        
        expense.setDate(formattedDate); 

I dont know if there a way to take input as dd/mm/yyyy format in the request instead of yyyy-mm-dd

but I want to store dd/mm/yyyy in the database no, don't bother with date format in database storage. ALWAYS store them as proper date object instead of strings in database. If you need custom date formatting, handle it at the presentation layer(e.g. frontend code)

You should never store date values as string, it's a design flaw. Store proper Date objects and the client application is responsible for proper display.

@WernfriedDomscheit You should never store date values as string, it's a design flaw. True, Store proper Date objects ... I hope you neither meant java.util.Date nor java.sql.Date. Use LocalDate in Java as the OP is wisely doing and use the database’s date data type and don’t worry about its format.

There is no way that a LocalDate can have any format. At all. Its toString method returns yyyy-mm-dd format. Always. There also is no way that you can rewrite its toString method. Nor should you want to.

This question is similar to: How to format LocalDate object to MM/dd/yyyy and have format persist. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also this and this.

The issue here is that the LocalDate object always uses the "yyyy-MM-dd" format for storage and parsing by default.
If you want to store the date in the "dd/MM/yyyy" format in your database, you need to convert the date to a string before storing it. However, typically, it's recommended to store dates in the standard "yyyy-MM-dd" format in the database for consistency and simplicity in handling date-related operations.
You can customize the deserialization of the LocalDate object in your request by using a custom deserializer.

public class CustomLocalDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String date = jsonParser.getText();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        try {
            return LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

Here your DTO request:

public class Expense {
    
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate date;

    // other fields, getters and setters
}

In this way you can get the localdate as you want.

Appreciated. I decided to stick to default format because I tried to implement filtering(by week, month and custom) but it did not work. Can I ask how would companies who operate in UK deal  with If they were developing an application that will be used by the public. I live in UK but I dont have a job yet, so I dont know who to ask

... LocalDate object always uses the "yyyy-MM-dd" format for storage and parsing by default. It does for parsing, that’s correct. It does not for storage, which fortunately isn’t relevant.
